# Running this script on Windows instead of Linux

Tags: python, tesseract

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/05/25/tesseract-ocr-text-localization-and-detection/), but I can't quite figure out the last part where he executes the script by typing

`$ python localize_text_tesseract.py --image apple_support.png`.

I'm guessing the author is on Linux, and so I've tried multiple ways to try and run this same very script on Windows, but when I try it Visual Studio just opens up and no OCR is run at all.

I've tried including the full path, for both the script and the image, running it in Python instead of Visual Studio, but to no avail.

Does anyone know how it ought to be typed into the terminal for Windows?

Comment: You should be able to run this script from a command shell. <Windows Key>+R, cmd<enter>.

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68568524/edit) including your script file contents and a screenshot of what appears when you type the command on the Windows' command prompt?

Comment: Hi everyone I found my problem! It was a lack of a parentheses. Thank you for your help